# Guice: A binding was already configured

Tags: java, guice

I have a piece of code with a couple of Modules from different libraries:

```
install(new AModule())
install(new BModule())
```

I am getting an error:-

> A binding to com.path.to.Class was already configured at com.AModule.provideClass.
> at com.BModule...

I need both the modules but they cannot be used together because both have bindings to a particular class. I do not own the 2 libraries so cannot make changes there. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

## Use [`Modules.override`](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Modules.html#override-com.google.inject.Module...-)

If you require the binding present in `AModule`, use:

```
install(Modules.override(new BModule()).with(new AModule()));
```

On the other hand, if you require the binding present in `BModule`, use:

```
install(Modules.override(new AModule()).with(new BModule()));
```